# Looking for fast "Find in Files" program

Tags: vb.net, search

I currently have a directory with 98,000 individual archive transaction files. I need to search those files for user input strings and have the option to open the files as it finds them or at the end of the search. I'm using Notepad++ currently and, while functional, it's quite slow. I thought about writing my own, but I am only familiar with .NET and I'm a beginner. Also, I'm not sure how efficient that would be compared to NP++.

This tool would be used again and again so the dev time would definitely be worth it if it came to that. Is there some other tool out there that's already developed that would accomplish this?

Comment: I've heard good things about this tool http://www.voidtools.com/, but I've never tried it myself.

Comment: Agent Ransack is much much faster then Astrogrep.  Looking at Astrogrep's source code, it uses a fairly straightforward .NET techinque: File.Open and StreamReader.ReadLine.  I wish Agent Ransack was open source.  They're doing something special.  I realize .NET has overhead, compared with unmanaged WIN32.  That's probably part of the secret.  But I also know that on UNIX mmap is substantially faster then fopen IO.  Not sure if the same is true on Windows.  Whatever is the fastest IO for Windows, Agent Ransack seems to have found it.

Comment: Astrogrep got the job done initially; however, I've since moved to Agent Ransack when on Windows. For *nix, grep does what I need.

Comment: If you've already got Cygwin in your Windows environment, try out `grep` in the terminal. You just need to open Cygwin.bat to launch the Cygwin terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you using [Astrogrep](http://astrogrep.sourceforge.net/), a grep utility for Windows. You can open files as it finds them, and it shows you the line where the match was found, without having to open the file.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. I downloaded this utility yesterday and it does everything I could possibly want. Thank you all for the suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

[Agent Ransack](http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home)

I've been using it for years.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the archive transaction files are plain text, you can download [CYGWIN](http://www.cygwin.com/) which is an environment providing UNIX tools for Windows.

Once that's done, you can open a new Cygwin Bash Shell, then do `cd 'c:\\foo'`  to get into the directory with your files, then do `grep -F -r "my string" *` to find your text. (The `-F` means it searches for that literal string as opposed to a regular expression and `-r` means recursive.)

Comment: Yeah, if you're already using Cygwin or Cygwin64, this is a good approach. It's much faster than my Notepad++ FindInFile searches. If you've never run the terminal before, go to your Cygwin directory and look for Cygwin.bat to launch it.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly overkill, but you could index the folder using [Lucene](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/), keep the index uptodate (as transaction files are added) and then searches will take trivial amounts of time, you can target the file, line and word number of each match for a given search string